# Full "package-path" versus import statement

Tags: java, import, package

This may be a very simple question but i haven't found an answer for it, maybe it's me that don't know what to google for, but here goes.

What's the difference between using a full "package-path" versus a import statement?

For example:

```
public java.sql.Date getDate(){
    return new java.sql.Date();
}
```

Versus:

```
import java.sql.Date;
/.../
public Date getDate(){
    return new Date();
}
```

Is there a difference?

Comment: There is no real difference. Your code gets shorter if you import the class. Imagine you are working with `that.is.a.very.very.very.and.so.on.long.path.name.MyClass`. A benefit of the full qualified version is to specify which class you are using without scrolling to the top of your code.

Comment: @StefanWarminski  does the longer method will not increase the compilation time as it need to be imported again and again when needed.

Comment: @javafan I don't know if there is a difference. But I don't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in the way things work. However in the case where you `import java.sql.Date` and then proceed to use it, you simply mean that whenever the `Date` class is used in this file, it is the class that is imported beforehand. If you don't import it and just use the `Date` class with its package name, you make no such assertions.

Importing and using just the class name is usually what you should do as the possibility of using classes with the same name is pretty low. In a case where you have classes with the same name in different packages, you may want to choose to not import them at all to make the distinction between the two classes more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

there is no such difference only difference is importing is easier than using its full path

> e.g. if you have to use many Date class it is harder to type each full
>   package path than to just import it